# CSS fixed distance won't work

Tags: css

Ok so i got this right now:
[Text with buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpBH5.png)

I want the buttons to be on the same line, even when the text is shorter then another.

I added the margin-top: 20pt;

```css
.vc_button-2-wrapper.vc_button-2-align-center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20pt;
}
```

It changes the distance, but the buttons are not on the same line..

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: We need the html code as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to make anything into a single line with the previous element then for that **"span" tag** is used and if you want the element to be in different line for that you should go with **"div" tag**.

In present problem use the button within the **"span" tag** and for sure  you will get the button in the same line which you want to do.

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Give all the boxes the same fixed height, and then give your button elements the following property: "vertical align: bottom".